# Regex help in python to find links

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I am parsing some links from an html page and I want to detect all links that match the following pattern:

```
http://www.example.com/category1/some-content-here/
http://www.example.com/category-12/some-content-here/
```

It should NOT match links below:

```
http://www.example.com/category1/
http://www.example.org/category-12/some-content-here/
```

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? Where did you fail?

Comment: Can you explain the pattern a bit more? You want `.com` urls that have multiple paths afterwards, not just 1?

Comment: This pattern: `http://www\..+?\.com/.+?/.+?/`

Comment: @MegaIng that allows for whitespace in urls.  Probably want something like [`http:\/\/www\.\w+\.com\/[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+\/[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+\/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/zzSZO9/2/)

Comment: @chrisz  - yes, trying to match exactly 3 paths - domain, category and the content, with the exact domain name, not any domain name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the HTML `a` tags, and then use regex to filter the original, full result:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
sample = """
<div id='test'>
    <a href='http://www.example.com/category1/some-content-here/'>Someting</a>
    <a href='http://www.example.com/category-12/some-content-here/'>Someting Here</a>
    <a href='http://www.example.com/category1/'>Someting1</a>
    <a href='http://www.example.org/category-12/some-content-here/'>Sometingelse</a>
 </div>
 """
a = [i['href'] for i in soup(sample, 'lxml').find_all('a') if re.findall('http://[\w\.]+\.com/[\w\-]+/[\w\-]+/', i['href'])]
```

Output:

```
['http://www.example.com/category1/some-content-here/', 'http://www.example.com/category-12/some-content-here/']
```